# is it possible to upload video on flickr using sharekit or other ios-sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to share video on Flickr . I have done lots of searching of net and group discussions but I didn't get any helpful data or links, so please give me some useful links and tutorial for uploading video on Flickr without giving me any negative votes.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  The way you avoid negative votes (or “downvotes” as we call them) is by asking good questions.  A good question tells us what you've tried: what code have you written?  What did it do that you didn't like?  What search terms did you use to search?  What web sites or discussion forums did you search?  Your question doesn't tell us any of those things.

Comment: so rob there is no help.and i told wat i have to tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look\study the flickr api? [(Link here)](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/) it tells you all the services you have available. It doesn't look like the best documentation, and i don't really know flickr but i don't see any mention of videos (don't know if it's even possible).

Hope this helps.